# JS Arrays, return elements with one greater value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having a bit of trouble with selecting arrays in an objects with greatest value.

Here is an object I end up having through series of functions.

```
{
    1252 = {
        [Monday, {
            Teacher1 = {
                Periods = [
                    [06/02/2023, 30/06/2023, 146 days]
                ]
            },
            Teacher2 = {
                Periods = [
                    [21/11/2022, 05/02/2023, 74 days]
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Basically it means : Ok I have two different teachers on Monday, with each a different period of occupation and the number of days for each.

What I'm looking to return is :

- for the reference 1252, the main teacher is Teacher1 (because he has 146 days of occupation), that info should be independant in an array like [[ref, day, mainTeacher, startDate, endDate, numberOfDays]]
- To be able to retrieve the info that there is a second Teacher with less days.

Thank you if you can help me get on the right track !

Best

Cédric

Comment: The syntax in the "code" you posted makes no sense.

Comment: Oh... This is a JSON.stringify(Obj) of where I'm at, sorry if it's weird

Comment: Nope it's not a JSON.stringify() of an object either.  It's not just weird it's incorrect format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First what you posted is not a JSON object, it does not follow JSON object notation. I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
const inputData = {
  "1252": [
    "Monday",
    {
      "Teacher1": {
        "Periods": [ [ "06/02/2023", "30/06/2023", "146 days" ] ]
      },
      "Teacher2": {
        "Periods": [ [ "21/11/2022", "05/02/2023", "74 days" ] ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

const result = [
  [ "1252", "Monday", "Teacher1", "06/02/2023", "30/06/2023", "146 days" ],
  [ "1252", "Monday", "Teacher2", "21/11/2022", "05/02/2023", "74 days" ],
]
```

```js
// Defined data cleanup method
function cleanData(data = null) {
  if (!data) return null;
  const result = [];

  // Loop through the data
  for (const ref in data) {
    const [day, teachers] = data[ref];

    // loop through the teachers
    for (const teacher in teachers) {
      const [[startDate, endDate, numberOfDays]] = teachers[teacher].Periods;

      // Gather all the data into result
      result.push([ref, day, teacher, startDate, endDate, numberOfDays]);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

function getMostDays( records=null ){
  if (!records) return null;
  let days;
  let result;

  // Loop through records
  for ( const record of records ){
    const [ ref, day, teacher, startDate, endDate, numberOfDays ] = record;

    // Convert string to int
    const len = parseInt( numberOfDays );

    // Compare previous record days with current record days
    if ( days && len < days ) continue;
    days = len;
    result = record;
  }

  return result;
}

function getLeastDays( records=null ){
  if (!records) return null;
  let days;
  let result;

  // Loop through records
  for ( const record of records ){
    const [ ref, day, teacher, startDate, endDate, numberOfDays ] = record;

    // Convert string to int
    const len = parseInt( numberOfDays );

    // Compare previous record days with current record days
    if ( days && len > days ) continue;
    days = len;
    result = record;
  }

  return result;
}

// Run data cleanup to get array of arrays
cleanData( inputData );

// Run to return the teacher with most days
getMostDays( cleanData( inputData ) );

// Run to return the teacher with least days
getLeastDays( cleanData( inputData ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is very interesting for me to understand it. I just have one last request if possible because that was the question also (if you see an easy answer) : How can I pick the one teacher who has the most days for one key reference ? Thank again

Comment: @Cedric depending on what the requirements are, you can keep these functions as is or you can combine them. For example instead of using ```result.push( ... )``` in the ```cleanData function```, you could use the ```convert and compare``` logic from ```getMostDays function```.